# Storing relationships in MySQL without JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, nodes

i want to store relationships in MySQL. So you can imagine there nodes (id, type,label) which are connected by the relationships. So my tables for storing the connections have the id's of both nodes which are connected.

First Problem: If i want to query in MySQL i have to use a lot of joins to search for nodes, which have the typ X and end point have label Y. That is very slow, but i do not want the relationship_table with typs.. because when editing i have to edit a lot of entrys.

Second Problem: If want to search for relationship which a relationship to someone else which have another condition it is hard with one table.. But how to store this more perfect? My structure is a bit non-relational but i cannot install anything on my server so that a lot of known systems won't work :(

Thanks for your help and suggestions..

Comment: JOINs are not inherently slow in MySQL, and trying to do what you're doing without doing any JOINs seems more than a little misguided. Have you put any time into ensuring that your tables have sensible indices and that your queries are optimal as well?

Comment: You don't want to implement a relational database because you are lazy but you want all the benefits of one. Yiesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the problem is solved now because i added a unique index which did suceed improving speed.. the question regarding better systems still exists but was not focus of question.